# Converting VBA XML reader to VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, vba

I am currently rewriting a VBA XML reader to a VB.net version for a project.  I have the following code in VBA:

```
    Dim XML_Doc As Object:  Set XML_Doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Dim XML_Detail As New ADODB.Recordset: XML_Detail.ActiveConnection = 
            "Provider=MSDAOSP; Data Source=MSXML2.DSOControl.2.6;"
```

I was told that I should be able to use almost the exact code in my VB.Net version but I am running into some problems.  I added as a reference to the VB.net project the Microsoft ActiveX 2.8 so I can use the ADODB.

The code in VB.Net is

```
    Dim XmlDoc As Object : XmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Dim XmlDetail As New ADODB.Recordset : XmlDetail.ActiveConnection = 
            "Provider=MSDAOSP; Data Source=MSXML2.DSOControl.2.6;"
```

When running the application it gets to the XmlDetail and throws the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled. 
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, 
or are in conflict with one another.
```

Does anyone have any experience with this or how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of work I found a solution:

```
Dim XmlDoc As Object : XmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XmlDetail.Open(DirSaveXml & ServiceName & ".xml", "Provider=MSDAOSP; Data Source=MSXML2.DSOControl.2.6;")
```

Comment: You would have done better to convert your code to use the .NET equivalents: `XmlDocument` and `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand`, and `OleDbDataReader`.

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to use MSXML in .Net:

The use of MSXML is not supported in .NET applications

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815112

Even More Details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/09/08/the-use-of-msxml-is-not-supported-in-net-applications.aspx